# Cypher: create or update query a node throws an error

Tags: cypher

Need some help insert or update using cypher.

I have the following cypher query:

```
cypher = 'MERGE (user:Person:User {email: {email}}) ON CREATE user = {props} SET user.created = timestamp() ON MATCH SET user.lastSeen = timestamp() RETURN user';
```

This seem to throw a error:

> ```
> errorError: Invalid input 'u': expected whitespace, comment or SET (line > 1, column 53)
> "MERGE (user:Person:User {email: {email}}) ON CREATE user = {props} SET > user.created = timestamp() ON MATCH SET user.lastSeen = timestamp() RETURN > user"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the first `SET`

```
cypher = '
    MERGE (user:Person:User {email: {email}}) 
    ON CREATE SET user = {props}, user.created = timestamp() 
    ON MATCH SET user.lastSeen = timestamp() 
    RETURN user';
```